# How to insert multiple values into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, I don't know exactly how to word this as I've never heard or done this but I'm sure someone has. Basically what I am doing is creating a listing for businesses, where fields such as phone numbers, other legal names, SIC codes, etc can have multiple values inserted into a column, for example there can be many phone numbers inserted into the phone number column in the table for that business. How would you achieve this both in mysql and php? Thanks!

Comment: you mean `num1,num2,num3,etc..` in a single field for a particular business? that's a bad database design.

Comment: What code Somy? It's just a concept at the moment. @marc why is it bad, is there a more logical way to achieve that aside from starting a new row simply to add an additional phone number? there is no way to determine how many phone numbers or sic codes, etc that any given company may have, however we are talking about a database containing over 200 columns per row :/

Comment: @nathan: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization   3rd normal form is how most people design tables. you'd split the phone numbers into their OWN table. that eliminates the phone field from the main table, and gives you the capability of unlimited phone numbers per company.

Comment: @MarcB thanks! I'll research this, seems to be the same concept of the many to one discussed below, so it seems to be a standard way of achieving it. Out of curiosity is it just bad organization or is there a functionality concern or what for the way I imagined initially?

Comment: it's more maintainability. consider having to add/change/delete a phone number in that list. any changes means a series of string operations, whereas having one record = one phone number you just update the entire field in a single go and you're done.

Comment: @MarcB that makes complete sense, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with what's called a **many-to-one**<sup>[1]</sup> relationship.

You have a `company` table, which would hold fields such as `companyID`, `name`, etc (all the single values (one-to-one) values).

Then, you have a `phones` table, which would reference the original `companyID`, while providing the information in multiple rows. For example:

```
company
-------
id | name
1  | Stack Overflow
2  | Hello World!

phones
------
comapnyID | phoneID | number
1         | 1       | 1234567890
1         | 2       | 0987654321
2         | 3       | 1234509876
```

This represents company 1 having two phone numbers, and company 2 having one.

You can easily select those with a MySQL JOIN clause.

<sub>1: One company may have multiple phone numbers, but a phone number can only belong to one company.</sub>

Comment: This is very descriptive and I believe exactly what I was looking for. I'll have to research it more thoroughly. It's greatly appreciated!

Comment: @madara: what about 1-800-OOPS-JEW (re: Stephen Colbert) which belongs to more companies each year?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to go that way, which is really bad, store the info (for example telephone numbers) as a single comma separated string (071124,421223,2244). 
Then, in php, use `$telephones=explode(',',$theString);`

Then you will have your numbers as an array ($telephones).

But I really don't recommend this.

Comment: Thank you Kiro for the response, if I may ask how would you achieve this if it were your project? I'm not necessarily looking to achieve it the way I described, that was just the only way I could imagine achieving it

Comment: @MadaraUchiha's anwer is the most accepted way to achieve what your looking for. And, as far as I know, the best one, when a relational database is in question.